# Asp.net load balancing SessionState

Tags: asp.net, nginx, load-balancing, session-state

We have 3 servers: *Server_web1,Server*_web2 and *Server_ngix*.
An asp.net application is installed on the servers *Server_web1* and *Server_web2*
The server *Server_ngix* processes client requests and executes [round-robin load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/round-robin-load-balancing/)
[image]

The session state is stored in the data base (it's configured in according with the [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/load-balancing-session-state-configuration/))

```
aspnet_regsql -d SessionStateDb -ssadd -S msserver -U sa -P 1 -sstype c
```

My web.config

[image]
[image]

The problem is that two sessions are created for one client: **SessionId1** on the server *Server_web1* and **SessionId2** on the server *Server_web2*, 
but one session is needed for each client.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create session by userId too which means store in database, restrict while creating new session until it expires.

Comment: But how to create session by userId?